# Error in c function while compiling linked library

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a simple example of a program (i.e. testHelloOuterWorld) calling a function from another linked program (i.e. testHelloWorld), but unfortunately facing what seems to be a very common declaration(?) error... I've tried searching for the actual error from many sources already, but its causes can be so many that I couldn't find my specific example.

See below, please:

```
$ make
gcc -g -Wall -c -o testHelloWorld.o testHelloWorld.c
gcc -g -Wall -o testHelloOuterWorld testHelloWorld.o -I. testHelloOuterWorld.c
testHelloOuterWorld.c: In function ‘testHelloWorld’:
testHelloOuterWorld.c:5:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
testHelloOuterWorld.c:8:1: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
 }
 ^
makefile:20: recipe for target 'testHelloOuterWorld' failed
make: *** [testHelloOuterWorld] Error 1
```

The first compilation works fine: testHelloWorld is compiled onto an object (to be later linked with testHelloOuterWorld). **testHelloWorld.c** has the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void testHelloWorld() {
    printf("\nhello, world");
}

int main() {
    // this file is to be linked to testHelloOuterWorld, so no actual main() usage
    return 0;
}
```

**testHelloWorld.h** declares the function I want to call from the testHelloOuterWorld program

```c
void testHelloWorld(void)
```

...and here's **testHelloOuterWorld.c**

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <testHelloWorld.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  testHelloWorld();
  return 0;
}
```

...so, what is wrong with the above testHelloOuterWorld.c compilation?

Comment: Errrrr... just found out the problem: I was missing a semicolon (;) at the testHelloWorld.h function declaration

Comment: Right, was just going to point that out.  The error is really in `testHelloWorld.h` even though it's reported while compiling `testHelloOuterWorld.c`.